# jquery $(this) in nested statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What happens when I want to refer to "this" in nested statements, which "this" does it use?

Here's an example to show what i mean by the above:

```
    $("input").blur(function(){
            var theThis = $(this);
            if(!($(".invalid").length > 0)){
                //if there's no messages already open
                theThis.data("validator").checkValidity();
            }else{
                //add the message to the next to be displayed
                nextToAlert.push(theThis);
                //bind an event to the errored field being changed
                $(".invalid").on("change", function(){
                    var me = $(this);
                    if(!me.hasClass('invalid')){
                        nextToAlert.pop().checkValidity();

                    }
                });
            }
    });
```

Comment: the element is selected, that's what happens

Comment: Yeah, not really a good question.

Comment: so the second this is the local one, and the first this is out of scope?

Comment: @Archer would you care to elaborate before downvoting?

Comment: `$(this)` is every single one of `.invalid`

Comment: What is wrong with the example?  What do you expect it to do?  What is it that is does?  What are you trying to do?  There's no information whatsoever.

Comment: The question is not about the example. The question is about the question. The example is to back it up

Comment: I have edited the question. Please reconsider your downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

- `theThis` refers to `$("input")`
- `me` revers to `$(".invalid")`

`$(this)` will always change depending on the current scope.

When you use any sort of action-binding function such as `blur`, `on`, `bind`, `live`, etc, then `$(this)` will refer to the current jQuery object that the event is being bound to.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this article](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/) to better understand `$(this)`. As an easy (not always corrent but in 99% cases) rule: `$(this)` will refer to element in question in current execution context (current location in DOM document).

In your example:

- `theThis` will be (current) `$("input")`
- `me` will be (current) `$(".invalid")`

Comment: if theres multiple `$(".invalid")`, `$(this)` only refer to one of them each time

Comment: Hence (current) `$("invalid")`. Same applies to `theThis`.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript uses function scope: the value of `this` depends on how the innermost function containing it was called. When you call `object.method()`, the value of `this` inside the method is `object`; if you call `function()`, the value of `this` is `window`. You can also set `this` to an arbitrary value by calling `function.call(thisValue)`. When the funcion is a callback, the value `this` takes depends entirely on the code which calls it back, so your primary source of information should be the jQuery documentation. But usually jQuery will set `this` to the DOM element on which the action happens. E.g. for `$('.foo').on('click', myFunc)` the value of `this` in `myFunc` will be the element which caught the click, for `$('.foo').each(myFunc)` it will be the current element in the collection, and so on. `$(this)` is then used to transform the DOM element into a jQuery element.